# Java - Comparing Lists

Tags: java, sorting, optimization

I have a program written in Java that reads in a file that is simply a list of strings into a LinkedHashMap. Then it takes a second file which consists of two columns and for each row see if the right-hand term matches one of the terms from the HashMap. The problem is it's running very slow.

Here's a code snippet, this is where it compares the second file to the HashMap terms:

```
String output = "";

infile = new File("2columns.txt");
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            System.out.println("2columns.txt" + " not found");
        }

        try {
            fw = new FileWriter("newfile.txt");

            out = new PrintWriter(fw);

            try {
                String str = in.readLine();

                while (str != null) {
                    StringTokenizer strtok = new StringTokenizer(str);

                    strtok.nextToken();
                    String strDest = strtok.nextToken();

                    System.out.println("Term = " + strDest);

                    //if (uniqList.contains(strDest)) {
                    if (uniqMap.get(strDest) != null) {
                        output += str + "\r\n";
                        System.out.println("Matched! Added: " + str);
                    }

                    str = in.readLine();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            out.print(output);
```

I got a performance boost from switching from an ArrayList initially to the LinkedHashMap but it's still taking a long time. What can I do to speed this up?

Comment: Profile your code and find the bottlenecks. Optimize the biggest one. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: FYI, I would use just HashMap rather than LinkedHashMap because the LinkedHashMap maintains not only the 'map' but a 'linked list' of all the values to preserve insertion order when iterating over the elements.  Unless you need that specific benefit, I'd change to HashMap.

Comment: I agree with @MДΓΓБДLL, your question is lacking sufficient information about WHERE the slowness in your application occurs.  Are the files so large that your app is swapping memory to disk?  Could the disk IO be very slow? How long does the current program take to run now?  How fast do you need it to run?  Inside your WHILE loop you instantiate a new StringTokenizer; object instantiation within loops is costly.  You're also using System.out.println within the loop, if your file is sufficiently large enough the printing could cause some slowness.  Identify where the slowness is coming from.

Comment: @DougAyers What would be a good alternative to the StringTokenizer then?

Comment: @StickFigs - Doug didn't SUGGEST that you use an alternative to StringTokenizer.  Read his comment again, carefully.  Matt Bell's advice is important too.

Comment: @DougAyers Also for your HashMap instead of LinkedHashMap suggestion, would that just save memory or would it also make the get() function for the HashMap go faster?

Comment: @StickFigs Btw you can use the `containsKey()` method for that test.

Comment: @trutheality - it *might* speed up the program more generally.  Insertion will be marginally faster, and using less memory can reduce the GC load which gives you a net speedup.

Comment: @StephenC After double-checking the source I realized you were right about `get()` -- there is an access update added. It won't speed up a `containsKey()` lookup though. Of course your point about general program speedup is also valid.

Comment: I figured out that the source of the slowdown was it maintaining the huge String "output". Once I told it to just write directly to a file it got much faster. Thanks all!

Comment: Oh, right, you actually create a new `String` and copy to it when you do `string += anotherString`, because `Strings` are immutable. A `StringBuilder` could have fixed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your major bottleneck may be that you are recreating a StringTokenizer for every iteration of the while loop. Moving this outside the loop could help considerably. Minor speed ups can be obtained by moving the String definition outside the while loop.

The biggest speedup will probably come from using a [StreamTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html%20%22StreamTokenizer). See below for an example.

Oh and use a HashMap instead of a LinkedHashMap as  @Doug Ayers says in the above comments :)

And @ MДΓΓ БДLL's suggestion of profiling your code is bang on. checkout this [Eclipse Profiling Example](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html)

```
    Reader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infile));
StreamTokenizer strtok = new StreamTokenizer(r);
String strDest ="";
while (strtok.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
    strDest=strtok.sval; //strtok.toString() might be safer, but slower
    strtok.nextToken();

    System.out.println("Term = " + strtok.sval);

    //if (uniqList.contains(strDest)) {
    if (uniqMap.get(strtok.sval) != null) {
        output += str + "\r\n";
        System.out.println("Matched! Added: " + strDest +" "+ strtok.sval);
    }

    str = in.readLine();
}
```

One final thought is (and I'm not confident on this one) that writing to a file may also be faster if you do it in one go at the end. i.e. store all your matches in a buffer of some sort and do the writing in one hit.

Answer (score 2):

StringTokenizer is a legacy class. The recommended replacement is the string "split" method.

Some of the trys might be consolidated. You can have multiple catches for a single try.

The suggestion to use HashMap instead of LinkedHashMap is a good one. Performance for gets and puts in a smidgeon faster since there is no need to maintain a list structure.

The "output" string should be a StringBuilder rather than a String. That could help a lot.